# React Navigation: When navigating with reset, refs become null

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a custom native component and I'm using its functions via ref.I'm also using react-navigation.

When I'm on Screen0 and navigate to Screen1 and navigate back to Screen0
Screen0's refs become null.If i navigate with NAVIGATE no error occurs.And if I'm on Screen0 for the first time refs are not null.Please help.

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch({type: 'Reset', index: 0, actions: [{ type: 
'Navigate', routeName:'Screen1',  params: {roomID: 
 this.props.navigation.state.params.roomID}}]});
```

This is the custom component

```
  <CustomViewExample  ref={((component)=>this.customView = component)} onLayout={this.onLayout} />
```